# Can XDMCP be encrypted with RSA or AES? Can XDMCP be forwarded over SSL or TLS?

Tags: x11, security, ssl, remote-desktop, xdmcp

I know XDMCP cannot be forwarded over SSH because XDMCP uses UDP and SSH uses TCP.
Can XDMCP be forwarded over SSL or TLS instead?
XDMCP is not encrypted by default. Can AES or RSA be added to XDMCP connection?